# Laravel 5 Blade. Blade subviews included on a view doesn't render Laravel specific code inside

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm experimenting an annoying trouble trying to display the content of a subview wihich is included into a view.

I was searching by the net solutions buy any of them be able to fix that.
I think I have all done correctly but, of course, something is wrong.

Simply, i load a view to be showed on the HTTP Controller as:

//LoginMainController

```
class LoginMainController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tech_info = TechInfoCliente::create();

        return View::make('login_main')->with('tech_info', $tech_info);
    }
}
```

Then, on the view i put some code inside the double braces provided by Laravel to inject the code on the view like:

```
//login_main.blade.php
(...)
{{!! HTML::style('css/360player.css') !!} 
(...)
{{Lang::get('knockeasy.signup')}}
(...)
//And then i tried to load a simple subview 
@include('player_360')


//player_360.blade.php
<div class="music"> 
    <label>{{Lang::get('knockeasy.music')}}</label>     
     (...) 
</div>
```

The html code of the subview is properly render with the view, but the tag *{{Lang::get('knockeasy.music')}}* is showed literally with the braces on the page (without process it).

What's wrong here?
I forgot something important?
I was thinking about if i must render the subview on the LoadMainController and add after to the final make view proccess, but i'm pretty sure of it can be achieved inside the self blade view throught special instructions.

Any ideas?

## Thanks to all.

**Fixed, partially with a dirty and ugly notation.**

Replacing

```
//player_360.blade.php
<div class="music"> 
    <label>{{Lang::get('knockeasy.music')}}</label>     
     (...) 
</div>
```

instead of:

```
 //player_360.blade.php
<div class="music"> 
    <label><?php echo Lang::get('knockeasy.music'); ?></label>      
     (...) 
</div>
```

But I'm really convinced of Blade engine is able to parse and render the double braces contained on the subview included

Comment: Are you sure that all of your views has `.blade` suffix?

Comment: Have you tried  @lang('knockeasy.signup')` instead?

Comment: @Ivanka Todorova, yes all my templates are correctly places, even the content of player_360 included is showed well, but the language tag inside between double braces is shown literally (without have been processed) That's the main issue.

Comment: @Jake Opena @lang('knockeasy.signup') and {{Lang::get('knockeasy.signup')}} works like a charm (identical), on the main view, but any of they works on the subview included. :(

Comment: do you have `player_360.php` along with `player_360.blade.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-5 change the way we use the tags `{{ }}` this tag now, in laravel-5, scape special characters, tags, and code.
And it gonna print like text every time you call it.

To print strings or variables with code you need to use the tags:

```
{!! !!}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't works neither.          <div class="music"> 
 <label>{!! Lang::get('knockeasy.music') !!}</label>

Comment: i think `knockeasy.music` is defined on the lang folder into your project? normally lang messages are only text.
What are you trying to print?

Comment: Yes, it was successfully shown with the trick explained above. But I'm not whole satisfied with it :(

Comment: It's just a label with text on both languages. It doesn't call any file or something else.

Answer (score 0):

in trait

```
public static function getTableView($modelClass)
{
    $tableName = $modelClass::getTableName();
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing( $tableName );

    $view = View::make("components/table", [
        "TableTitle" => $modelClass::DISPLAYNAME_IN, 
        "prefix" => $modelClass::PREFIX,
        "Columns" => $columns
        ]);

    $result = $view->render();
    return $view;
}
```

in controller

```
$table = $this->getTableView(SugarFactory::class);

    return view('sugar_factories/list_sf', ["table" => $table ]);
```

in view

```
{!! $table !!}
```